# What does "klioklio" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, literature, poetry

I'm reading Malcolm Lowry's letters and his second letter to Conrad Aiken finishes like this:

*Klioklio*, C. M. Lowry

Does anyone know what "*klioklio*" mean? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A French scholar to the rescue - thesis by Pierre Schaeffer, 2005 - Université Lumière Lyon 2

> Dans sa deuxième lettre du 12 mars 1929, c’est la restitution du **bruit
> des mouettes** que Lowry empruntera à Aiken pour clore sa lettre : «
> Klioklio, C.M. Lowry » (SL, p.7/ CL1, p. 64).

My translation

In his second letter of March 12, 1929, it is the representation of **the cry of seagulls** that Lowry borrows from Aiken to close his letter

[Hambo le prédateur : dévoration et phagocytose du Père (note 361)](http://theses.univ-lyon2.fr/documents/getpart.php?id=lyon2.2005.schaeffer_p&part=105419)

Comment: Klio is a quite common word for the sound of gulls; used sometimes for the names of boats.

Comment: Malcolm used it in his poetry as well: https://books.google.com/books?id=5ovein5mkzMC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=klioklio+malcom+lowry&source=bl&ots=aub4QEanKY&sig=ACfU3U3bz_BfDsTAWHbgY2y2s3YO5D1hWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj08OWZkqzuAhVeIDQIHXDaDvkQ6AEwC3oECAcQAQ